# Retrieving list of modified files in GitHub action

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm currently using [foo-software/lighthouse-check-action](https://github.com/foo-software/lighthouse-check-action) to have audits done automatically. But since the `urls` have to be hard-coded in, it doesn't prove that useful when wanting to audit only the modified pages in a commit and failing based off of those.

Is there a way to achieve the above? I was looking at some actions like [actions/get-changed-files](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-changed-files) but I can't get it to work. I also looked at the GitHub events and references docs and was unable to figure out something with those.

Comment: Try this github repo - https://github.com/aseem-hegshetye/gha-files-changed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[lots0logs/gh-action-get-changed-files](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-changed-files) action is broken atm due to [this](https://github.com/lots0logs/gh-action-get-changed-files/issues/10) bug. Take a look at [jitterbit/get-changed-files](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-all-changed-files) action. It works perfectly for me:

#### .github/workflows/test.yml

```yaml
name: Test

on: push

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
      - uses: jitterbit/get-changed-files@v1
        id: abc
        with:
          format: space-delimited
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Printing
        run: |
          echo "All:"
          echo "${{ steps.abc.outputs.all }}"
          echo "Added:"
          echo "${{ steps.abc.outputs.added }}"
          echo "Removed:"
          echo "${{ steps.abc.outputs.removed }}"
          echo "Renamed:"
          echo "${{ steps.abc.outputs.renamed }}"
          echo "Modified:"
          echo "${{ steps.abc.outputs.modified }}"
          echo "Added+Modified:"
          echo "${{ steps.abc.outputs.added_modified }}"
```

#### Logs output:

```
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5267496Z All:
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5268424Z .github/workflows/test.yml .tidy-renamed2 Test.ts hello.py
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5268537Z Added:
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5268609Z hello.py
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5268697Z Removed:
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5268787Z Test.ts
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5268880Z Renamed:
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5269260Z .tidy-renamed2
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5269357Z Modified:
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5269450Z .github/workflows/test.yml
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5269547Z Added+Modified:
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5269625Z .github/workflows/test.yml hello.py
2020-05-15T13:47:15.5306656Z Post job cleanup.
```

Comment: At the moment this does not work, it seems that if you have squashed commits it just returns an empty list https://github.com/jitterbit/get-changed-files/issues/11#issuecomment-718254652.

Comment: It seems it was fixed in a forked repo (https://github.com/Ana06/get-changed-files/releases/tag/v1.2), so people actually can use it for now. Or specify commit hash instead of tag where it used to work, e.g. jitterbit/get-changed-files@b17fbb0

Answer (score 8):

After trying unsuccessfully with both plugins above and some more I have resorted to the following:

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
- name: (CI) Dependencies update check
  run: |
    current_commit=`git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H`
    echo $current_commit
    last_deps_mod_commit=`git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- composer.json`
    echo $last_deps_mod_commit
    if [ $current_commit == $last_deps_mod_commit ]; then echo USE_LOCK=0 > ci.conf; else echo USE_LOCK=1 > ci.conf; fi
```

Observe that it must be a full checkout (depth 0) not a flat one otherwise it will always return true.