# How to check out only changed files and capture in array?

Tags: github-actions

I am creating a GitHub Actions workflow for accomplishing the following:

- Looking for YAML files in my repo that have been changed on the most recent push.
- Checking these files out.
- For each changed/checked-out file, calling CURL to post these files do a different site.

The workflow looks something like this:

```yaml
name: "Publish API References"
on: 
  push:
    branches: 
      - master
      - main-github-test
    paths:
      - '**.yaml'
      - '**.yml'
jobs:
  deployment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check Out Changed Files
        uses: Bhacaz/checkout-files@v2
        with:
         files: <retrieve array of only changed files>

    - name: Create/Update API References on our API Definition site
      run: |
        files=(array of filenames captured from previous step)
        for file in ${files[@]}
            do
          curl --request POST \
            --verbose \
            --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
            --header "X-Api-Key: ${{secrets.API_KEY}}" \
            --form file=@$file \
            --url "https://our.api.specs.site"
            done
        echo Done
```

but I cannot get it to work.  Nor can I find any examples of others doing something like this.

As you can see, I am using `Bhacaz/checkout-files@v2` but I've also experimented with other checkout utilities.  This one seems to require a hardcoded list of file paths; perhaps there are others that allow a way to dynamically retrieve a list of filenames via a wildcard or by scanning the repo for changed files.

And then there is the challenge of *capturing* that list/array of files for use in the "Create/Update References....." step - so that I can use that list to build a bash script array that is looped through.

I simply want to collect files that match a certain pattern that were changed/pushed, check them out, and then send them to a remote site.

Comment: Why don't you check out all the files _then_ find out which files were changed in the last commit (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59288971/3001761)?

Comment: This is going to be really hard, since github doesn't give you access to the `push` data, so you can't know which files have changed since the last push unless you drop some kind of low-watermark label you can reference.

Comment: You can compare against the latest commit, but that's not guaranteed to be all the commits that were pushed. You can probably also grab the commit hash from the logs of the previous action workflow run as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I found a possible way to retrieve a collection of changed file names - however, it seems that the `paths:` argument in my `on: push` isn't working.  I specified '.yaml' and '.yml', each preceded by 2 asterisks (I can't actually use the asterisks in this comment because markup interprets them as bold font), but when I change/commit these files, they get ignored.  Am I using this correctly?  My assumption is that these patterns would search recursively throughout my entire repo for files with the yaml or yml extension.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that answered my question (at least sufficiently for the task I'm working on.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - to clarify my last comment: my `paths:` argument doesn't seem to work.  The expectation is that my action should be triggered whenever any file anywhere in my repo that ends with .yml or .yaml is changed/committed.  But it doesn't work when I test it.  In order for my action to be triggered when yml/yaml files are altered, I need to remove the `paths:` speficier.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?