# How to run lint only on the files in PR

Tags: python, github, github-actions, pylint

I am running pylint in GitHub but it is running on all the files in repo for every PR as I am using `pylint $(git ls-files '*.py')`. How can I run it only for the files present in the pull request? Below is my workflow file:

```yaml
name: Python Linting
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install pylint
      - name: Lint with Pylint
        run: |
          pylint $(git ls-files '*.py')
```

I am using `$(git ls-files '*.py')` need a command to run it only on the changed file. The script is running on Windows

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59288971/retrieving-list-of-modified-files-in-github-action

Comment: For one thing, some of the builds won't be on PRs at all (according to the trigger rules in `on:`). For another, why _not_ lint the whole codebase? You can check just the staged files locally, to make sure you're not introducing issues, but the CI pipeline should make sure _everything_ is still OK.